# PHP preg_split() with conditional formatting

Tags: php, split

If I have to parse a string that includes comments which might contain delimiter syntax how would I handle it in PHP?

Let the input string be:

```
"56.82[This is a comment], 43.78, 62.55[Comment 2, but with delimiter identifiers], 33.21"
```

How could I parse this string so that I can echo the two sections like so:

```
56.82 - This is a comment
43.78
62.55 - Comment 2, but with delimiter identifiers
33.21
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it may be easier to use `preg_match_all` instead.

```
preg_match_all("/[0-9.]+(\[.*?\])?/",$input,$matches);
```

In this way, you can iterate through the `$matches` array (`var_dump` it to see the structure) which is much more reliable than trying to split the text.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'm trying to figure out how to incorporate this into my code

Answer (score 0):

You can use [preg_quote()](https://www.php.net/preg_quote) to espace the string before using preg_ functions.

Comment: And this helps... how?

Comment: This will escape the delimiters that might be in the string, in this case the "[" character, for example

Comment: O...kay? Pretty sure the entire question is to do with the fact that comments may contain commas, which are also used to delimit items.